# In Qt tell the main class that an item was clicked

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent

**Situation**:

I have a `Dialog` class in QT on which I draw a raster of squares. The squares are implemented in the `MySquare` class (`MySquare: QGraphicsItem`).

Inside the MySquare there are a number of functions (mysquare.h protected: )

```
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
```

When I click on a square it gives me the relative coordinates of the square using the following function.

```
void MySquare::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    update();
    QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(event);
    qDebug() << "mouse Pressed";
    qDebug() << "coordinates:";
    qDebug() << "X:"<< x/w << " Y:" << y/h ;
}
```

[image]

Where x and y are the x and y position in the raster and w and h stand for width and height

However my **question** is how can I let my Dialog class know what square was clicked on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can communicate between `MySquare` and and your Dialog by means of the signal/slot mechanism of Qt.
When a square gets clicked, it emits a signal, and the Dialog has a slot that is connected to that signal.

To identify *which* square sent the signal, there are several possibilities:

- The coordinates of the square are passed along in the signal
- The `this` pointer of the `MySquare` that emits the signal is passed along
- In the slot, you can use the `sender` function to determine who emitted the signal.